# Importing custom python module

Tags: python, import, pip, python-module, python-wheel

I am creating pip package and before submitting I would like to try it. For simplification, lets assume that python script looks like this:

```
def foo():
    print("Hello World!")
```

My  `setup.py` containing metadata looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

    setup(
        name="test_super_secret",
        version="1.0",
        description="testing pip version 1",
        packages=find_packages(),
    )
```

I have compiled script using `Wheel`, so that I'm able to install it via pip :

```
user@pc:$ python -m pip install dist/test_super_secret-1.0-py2-none-any.whl 
Processing ./dist/test_super_secret-1.0-py2-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: test-super-secret
Successfully installed test-super-secret-1.0
```

However, when I'm not able to import such module from python:

```
    >>> import test-super-secret
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    import test-super-secret
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I doing wrong? Should I import it in another way or should I change setup so that it would be possible to import module?

EDIT:
Module can not be imported even if it is called `testsupersecret` in the `setup.py`:

```
>>> import testsupersecret
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named testsupersecret
```

Answer (score 0):

`test-super-secret` is not a valid module name -- you can't have hyphens in the module names (or variables), python thinks this is a minus sign, that's why you get invalid syntax. You should use underscores (which you probably already are using based on your `setup.py` -- `name="test_super_secret"`, just try importing `test_super_secret`).

(Python packages can have hyphens in the name, that's probably where the confusion comes from. So `test-super-secret` is a valid name for pip package, but the module must be named `test_super_secret`.)

Comment: `test-super-secret` is not a valid module name, that is true. However, when I change the name to `testsupersecret` in `setup.py`, I'm still not able to import such a module with error: `ImportError: No module named testsupersecret`.
Anyway, from the original question, where did pip even get name `test-super-secret` from? Is it the name from `setup.py` with changed underscores to hyphens?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I did not have correct folder structure to get modules as a library. Once I created directory containing `__init__.py` and move my script to that directory, I was able to import module like `import <MyLibrary>.<my_script_name>`